# Redirecting in specific address

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I use codeigniter for my project. On localhost i dont have any problems with my application. When i put files on server i have a big problem with .htacces i think. I have a address: `domain.com/napijmy_sie/index` work but address `domain.com/napijmy_sie/app` doesn't work. Why? I dont have any idea. Here is my .htacces file:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /napijmy_sie
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try this --

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /napijmy_sie/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ napijmy_sie/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I hope it should work.

Comment: can you let me know the server where you hosted like godaddy or something else and project directory path that where you placed all proect related files

Comment: you can visit this answer that may help you also -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119420/code-igniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Comment: server = stampa.pl hosted on cal.pl
path = napijmy_sie

Comment: check the other settings too that may be issue., and also check the server forum as there are difference in .htaccess for some servers..